# Q: how to deal with cygwin installing error at mirror download step ？

Tags: cygwin, mirror

install cygwin on win7/32bit,run setup-x86.exe to mirror download site step,problem appear，the image below is error screenshot ，i tried many times and  different sites just does not work.does setup.exe not support these sites or something wrong with site's file.please help~

***error screenshot***

[image]

Comment: This is NOT a programming question, so Superuser or better the cygwin mailing list is the right place. https://cygwin.com/lists.html . It is possible that there is an arror in the program that does not run on Your W7/32bit. I have no problem to re-install gcrypt on my W10 with Cygwin 32bit. On Cygwin mailing list follows https://cygwin.com/problems.html guidelines. Are you using the latest Cygwin Setup https://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe ?

Comment: I am sure that the exe is download from offical site automatically，but i am not sure whether it is the latest.now i try to use GIt for windows for it's bash,anyway thank u